# How to read the entire "Unauthorized changes blocked" message?

Tags: windows-10, notification-area, windows-defender

From time to time, Windows Defender (via Controlled Access Folder) blocks apps from accessing my files and raises a notification on the Windows notification bar.

The notification looks like the following:

[image]

And I'm wondering, how can I get the full message? Where can I see the full path to `gedit.exe` of the screenshot above, so I can add it to the excluded/authorized apps list?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Alas that's the shortest I managed to find:

It's in the

- Event Viewer

  - Application and Services

    - Microsoft

      - Windows

        - Windows Defender

          - Operational

The info about the program that triggered the error is all in there. I can then just copy the program's path and paste it into the allowed apps, via:

- Windows Defender Security Settings

  - Virus and Threat Protection

    - Virus and Threat Protection Settings

      - Controlled Folder Access / Allow an app through Controlled Folder Access

        - Add an allowed app

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 for the good answer; hope Microsoft will soon realise, and provide a "warning" log viewer for the same!